# Node.js Async not working properly with whilst or forever

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

I have data in a database which i would like to accumulate. Therefore I need a function that is called reapeatedly several times but not in parallel. It should wait for the function before to finish. 
I have encoutered async and was trying to call the function multiple times but the loop iteration happens only once...

```
function callDocAccumulation() {
    var db = openSQL();
    db.serialize(function() {
        db.get(batchSQL.queryProgramLineCount, function(err, row) {
            var count = 0;
            console.log('count rows ' + row.size);
            var async = require('async');
            async.whilst(function() {
                return count < row.size
            }, function(next) {
                docAccumulation();
                console.log('counter whilst ' + count)
                count++;
                /*added function*/
                setTimeout(next, 1000); 
            }, function(err) {
                console.log(err);
            });
        });
    });
    db.close();
}

function callDocAccumulation2() {
    console.log('callDocAccumulation2')
    var async = require('async');
    var err = function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    };
    var call = function() {
        console.log('first call of docAccumulation')
        docAccumulation();
    };
    async.forever(call, err);
}
```

the docAccumulation is a bit more complex. I am checking if a line exists that has not been processed. Then I look if i can be accumulated because in the other table an entry exists otherwise it is the start of the accumulation.

```
function docAccumulation(){
    var db = openSQL();
    db.serialize(function() {
        db.get(batchSQL.queryProgramLine, function(err, row) {
            var idProgram = row.idProgram;
            var Name = row.Name;
            var ProgramName = row.ProgramName;
            var ProgramPath = row.ProgramPath;
            var DocumentPath = row.DocumentPath;
            var StartDate = new Date(row.StartDate);
            var EndDate = new Date(row.EndDate);
            var seconds = (EndDate.getTime() - StartDate.getTime())/1000;
            console.log(seconds);
            console.log(batchSQL.queryProcessedLine(row.Name,row.ProgramName,row.DocumentPath));
            db.get(batchSQL.queryProcessedLine(Name,ProgramName,DocumentPath), function(err, row) {
                if(row === undefined || row === null){
                    var stmt = db.prepare(batchSQL.insertRowProc);
                    stmt.run([Name, ProgramName, ProgramPath, DocumentPath, seconds], function(error){
                        console.log('lastInsert ' + this.lastID);
                        var stmt = db.prepare(batchSQL.updateRowProgram);
                        stmt.run(this.lastID, idProgram);
                        stmt.finalize();
                    }); 
                    stmt.finalize();
                }else{
                    console.log('seconds before ' + seconds);
                    console.log('seconds row.time ' + row.Time);
                    seconds += row.Time;//increment time
                    console.log('seconds after ' + seconds);
                    var stmt = db.prepare(batchSQL.updateRowProcessed);
                    stmt.run([seconds, row.idProcessed], function(error){
                        console.log('lastInsert ' + row.idProcessed);
                        var stmt = db.prepare(batchSQL.updateRowProgram);
                        stmt.run(row.idProcessed, idProgram);
                        stmt.finalize();
                    }); 
                    stmt.finalize();
                }
            });
        });
});
}
```

Where is my error? No matter what function I call the loop is only called once. From the log I can see, that the number of rows is higher. 
Would recursion be smarter here?

Comment: `whilst` will run in parallel. Use `eachSeries`.  Read the [doc](https://github.com/caolan/async#eacharr-iterator-callback) carefully on when to call `callback()`.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? In general terms, that is.

Comment: @hassansin: Uh, no, `whilst` will do nothing in parallel?

Comment: @Silve2611: Please show us your `docAccumulation` function. Btw, you're not getting to the second iteration because the `callback` is never called.

Comment: @Bergi Yup, his code for doAccumulation will only run for the first time since no `next()` is called inside.  But as he wants to run it in series, `eachSeries` will be better.

Comment: I am not sure i can apply eachSeries. I do not have an array with data. I just want the function to be called as many times as there are entries in the database.

Comment: adding setTimeout(next, 1000); solved it for me but i think this is bad for the performance. is there a smarter way?

Comment: @Silve2611: Again - show us your code for `docAccumulation` and we can tell you.